# Proxy not displaying full app for Node Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am new to the entire *MERN* Stack process.

I am following the tutorial for a user login app here:

https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-a-login-auth-app-with-mern-stack-part-1-c405048e3669

I've reached the end of the tutorial, and I feel I am missing a crucial step. If I run

```
npm run dev
```

I can successfully view and use the app at

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Here is the script for `dev` in my root `package.json`:

```
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
```

However, isn't it also supposed to work if I run

```
node server.js
```

If I do this, I get this error at `localhost:5000`

```
Cannot GET /
```

I have a proxy setting in my client's `package.json` is well. Isn't this supposed to let me access the full app at

```
localhost:5000
```

Here is my root `package.json`:

```
    "name": "example",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "example",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
        "start": "node server.js",
        "server": "nodemon server.js",
        "client": "npm start --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
      },
      "author": "mystock",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.3.11",
        "passport": "^0.4.0",
        "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
        "validator": "^10.9.0"
      }}
```

Here is my `client/package.json`

```
        {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

I'd appreciate any input!

Comment: Try running command `npm start` in your react.js folder

Comment: Hi @sagar! Thanks for your suggestion. When I do this it appears to run the         "start": "node server.js", from the package.json, so I still get the same "error" on port 5000. The tutorial says that both server and client should be able to run at the same time. And it does with the concurrently plugin, but I want to just run npm start and have it so I can view the client. 

In the client subdirectory's package.json, it lists this line: 

client/package.json:  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"  So I feel I should be able to access the login client without the "Cannot GET /" message.